# Set width of a form inside a div, to the max-width of it's parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div style='float: left; width: 50%; background-color: #00243c;'>
    <div style='float:right; max-width: 500px;'>            
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est montes vitae. Auctor ipsum nam est, phasellus id condimentum facilisis. Aliquam sem, pede nec ante. Magnis phasellus mi neque, nullam quis lobortis, tristique adipiscing at. Amet arcu, donec sodales elit quis odio, suspendisse pede natoque amet leo, ipsum ac vivamus, amet fusce eget. Tortor augue eget montes metus nullam.
    </div>
</div>
<div style='float: left; width: 50%; background-color: white;'>
    <div style='float: left; max-width:500px;'>
      <form style='width:100%;'>
         <input type='text' value='test' style='width:100%'>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure, that the `form` will always take up the maximum allowed width of it's parent `div`.

So, for example, if the second main `div` is at least 500px wide(that means if that the screen is at least 1000px wide), the `form` inside the left floated `div` with a max-width of 500px, will take up 500 px, BUT, if the screen width is less then 1000 px, let's say for example 800, the `form` will only take up 400 px, as the width of it's parent?

Here's a fiddle also:
https://jsfiddle.net/f864b29a/

Comment: The form _is_ the width of it's parent. the parents width is collapsing because you are floating it. https://jsfiddle.net/f864b29a/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the float from the wrapping div, because it just shouldn't float, It will stick to the left as you wish and will expand at max of 500 pixels. Yet I don't find this structure as a reasonable layout, just my thought.

https://jsfiddle.net/f864b29a/4/

```
<div style='max-width:500px;'>
  <form style='width:100%;'>
     <input type='text' value='test' style='width:100%'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not realy sure, but maybe this is what you want:

```html
<div style='float: left; width: 50%; background-color: #00243c;'>
    <div style='float:right; max-width: 500px;'>            
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est montes vitae. Auctor ipsum nam est, phasellus id condimentum facilisis. Aliquam sem, pede nec ante. Magnis phasellus mi neque, nullam quis lobortis, tristique adipiscing at. Amet arcu, donec sodales elit quis odio, suspendisse pede natoque amet leo, ipsum ac vivamus, amet fusce eget. Tortor augue eget montes metus nullam.
    </div>
</div>
<div style='float: left; width: 50%; background-color: orange;'>
    <div style='float: left; width: 100%; max-width:500px;'>
      <form style='width:100%;'>
         <input type='text' value='test' style='width:100%'>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```