# setting the width of elements in a form (and inside a DIV)

Tags: html, forms, input, width

I need a little push here.  I'm helping out a friend with a validation process.  I tried to implement the solution here:  [Set width of a form inside a div, to the max-width of it's parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108989/set-width-of-a-form-inside-a-div-to-the-max-width-of-its-parent)

but didn't work for me.  my HTML is rusty.  I'd like the input text box to be 500px in width.  Here is my form code:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;">
<form action="validation.php" method="post" name="frm" style="width:100%;">
    <center><br />
     Enter Your Product Key:<br />
        <input type="text" id="key" name="key" style="width:100%"/><br />
    </center>
  <p>
    <center><input type="submit" id="valcheck" value="Validate My Product Key" /></center>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?  thanks.

DANIEL, I saved it into the post.  see below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Validation Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="max-width:500px;">
    <form action="validation.php" method="post" name="frm" style="width:100%;">
        <center><br />
         Enter Your Product Key:<br />
           <input type="text" id="key" name="key" style="width:100%"/><br />
        </center>
      <p>
       <center><input type="submit" id="valcheck" value="Validate My Product Key" /></center>
      </p>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the snippet tool?  I don't post here on SO very often.  I assume you're talking about a tool located here on this site?

Comment: I think my lack of posting here is showing Daniel.  I don't see any icon on the SO page like you describe.  are you describing an icon in the browser app like firefox perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ covers everything - except , sadly, the image they portray is out of date.   It's the last one on the menu bar:    https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/wmd-buttons.svg?v=8b134e4f9bb0

Comment: I edited my post Daniel.  by the way, how in the world do I post actual REPLIES here instead of just adding comments to this conversation of ours!?  I can't find out how to do that either!  There is no option on my page here.

Comment: I edited it my post and saved the snippet in it for you.  as I said before, the snippet runs just fine.  furthermore, I can't most these "comments" of ours to a "chat" as i get an error messages saying "user[xxxxx] only has 17 reputation points.  not enough to move to chat".

Comment: Are you saying that you can't reproduce the problem in your snippet?

Comment: the snippet works perfectly Daniel.  so no, I can't reproduce the issue using a snippet here on SO.

Comment: The question has <br /> - we don't use this - it is <br>.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem here, that implies it's caused by something that you didn't include here for us to find.

Comment: I added the code exactly as it was in my file daniel. so this is not going to be solved.  I will produce a workaround without a SO solution.  thanks for trying.

Comment: It's smart to add `input type="password"` here.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead of HTML:

```
form {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

You can `max-width` your whole form because the text and the button are less than 500px anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a separate .css file for styling.

Comment: Where has @AdamEvanovich used CSS in his question?

Comment: he hasn't. but I think he should. I meant that he should create a .css file and link it to the html

Comment: this is a solution for a ms access programmer.  including a css file as a link in the html file will only add confusion.  I gave him the solution without solving this issue.  it was a minor annoyance anyway.  thanks guys.